# C# Regular Expression for this

Tags: regex

what would be the regular expression to match the below phrases, and find each parentheses content seperately

GetGlobalResourceObject("Misc", "HideHiddenRoomTypes")

So I would like to locate the above phrase and be able to replace "Misc" and "HideHiddenRoomTypes" with something else, by using the RegEx.Replace method or something similar.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What if your phrase is something like `one")two("three`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
GetGlobalResourceObject\(\"(?<Match1>.*)?\",\s\"(?<Match2>.*)?\"\)
```

You'll match the 2 words in quotations as `Match1` and `Match2`